# Grade assessment with the use of javascript

Tags: javascript

i need help with this code written below. l would like to run it with the use of function

```
var score = 100;
prompt ("Enter student score");


if (score <= 95 || score == 100) {
    document.write (" A");
} else if (score <= 85 || score == 95){
    document.write ("B");
} else if (score <= 75 || score == 85){
    document.write ("C"); 
}else if (score <= 60 || score ==75){
    document.write ("D");
}else if (score <= 50 || score == 60){
    document.write ("E");
}else if (score <= 40 || score == 50){
    document.write ("F");
}
else {
    document.write (' Dropout.');
}
```

Comment: Wrap it like `function assessment(score) { /* your if statements */ }` and call as `assessment(score)`.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
if (score <= 95 || score == 100) {
```

works not as intended, because it checks if a value is smaller or equal to `95` OR is equal to `100`.

It does not check the range between, for example a score of `98`.

Beside this, you got a string from `prompt` and not a number.

---

You need a working greade check first, probably by using a check beginning from the largetst value to the smallest for a grade (maybe you need to check with `>=`).

Then wrap the code in a function and use an early exit approach, where a check is made and the function exits directly with a value.

```js
function getGrade(score) {
    if (score > 95) return 'A';
    if (score > 85) return 'B';
    if (score > 75) return 'C';
    if (score > 60) return 'D';
    if (score > 50) return 'E';
    if (score > 40) return 'F';
    return 'Dropout.'
}

console.log(getGrade(+prompt ("Enter student score")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getGrade = score => score > 95 ? 'A' : score > 85 ? 'B' : score > 75 ? 'C' : score > 60 ? 'D' : score > 50 ? 'E' : score > 40 ? 'F' : 'Dropout'
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: l really appreciate u all.Thanks